# Bits aren't being reset?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I am using Bit Scan Forward to detect set bits within a unit64_t, use each set bit index within my program, clear the set bit and then proceed to find the next set bit. However, when the initial uint64_t value is:

> 0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The below code isn't resetting the 52nd bit, therefore it gets stuck in the while loop:

```
uint64_t bits64 = data;

//Detects index being 52
int32_t index = __builtin_ffsll(bits64);

while(0 != index){

    //My logic

    //Set bit isn't being cleared here
    clearNthBitOf64(bits64, index);

    //Still picks-up bit 52 as being set
    index = __builtin_ffsll(bits64);
}

void clearNthBitOf64(uint64_t& input, const uint32_t n) {
    input &= ~(1 << n);
}
```

Comment: This is clearly C++, not C.

Comment: Okay, so it needs to be index-1 for clearing the bit, not index.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

> — Built-in Function: `int __builtin_ffs (int x)`
>   Returns **one plus the index** of the least significant 1-bit of x, or if x is zero, returns zero.

You're simply off by one on your clear function, it should be:

```
clearNthBitOf64(bits64, index-1);
```

Also your `clear` function is overflowing. You need to ensure that what you're left shifting is of sufficient size:

```
void clearNthBitOf64(uint64_t& input, const uint32_t n) {
    input &= ~(1ULL << n);
    //          ^^^
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was aware of this, I tried decrementing the argument to the function and I was still getting the problem, hence I was totally puzzled. Weren't sure if my clear function was wrong.

Comment: @user997112 Added the other problem.

Comment: It was the overflowing! Could you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: @user997112 `1` is an int. Also, shifting by the width of a type (or more) causes undefined behaviour. So if your system has 32-bit ints then `1 << 32` and `1 << 52` etc. are all undefined.

Comment: @M.M ah thanks, I didnt realise the size of the shift value affected the result of the target value (being shifted).

Comment: @M.M so would it be better if I made the signature const uint64_t n to match the size of the input?

Comment: @user997112 not sure what you meant by the "I didn't realise" comment - the type of the second operand doesn't matter, the type of the first operand does. If you shift an `int` the result is an `int` ; if you shift a `uint64_t` the result is a `uint64_t`.  You are intending to shift a 64-bit int so you need to write `1ull` (or similar) instead of `1`  .  `const uint64_t &input` doesn't seem appropriate here as then you would not be able to modify `input` .  The type of `n` doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

`__builtin_ffsll` "returns one plus the index of the least significant 1-bit of x, or if x is zero, returns zero." You need to adjust the left shift to `~(1ULL << (n - 1))` or change the function call to `clearNthBitOf64(bits64, index - 1);`